# Desktop PC failing to connect to Wifi

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

Since yesterday, my desktop PC has trouble connecting to my WiFi network. I'm not sure what happened yesterday, but I think my ISP had a small outage.

Since then, my Android phones are perfectly back in the Wifi, but my desktop still can't manage it. It sporadically tends to connect for a minute after I reset my router before losing connection until the next reset again. Although that doesn't happen consistently as well.

My desktop connects to the Wifi via USB Wifi stick. It can properly detect my and other wifis, but when trying to connect, I am just getting a very generic try to verify and connect, ending up in the message "Can't connect to this network".

What I already tried:

- Forget and rename the network. This helped somewhat for one time, but not reproducible.
- Reinstall network and USB WiFi stick drivers
- Connect to my phones hotspot. Works perfectly.

Although nothing here helped.

Any ideas? I'm running Windows 10, on a side note.

EDIT: I noticed that my network adapter switches to disabled for a moment when trying to connect, and then goes right back again before a failure is reported.

Comment: Try another USB Wifi stick, or try it on another computer.

Comment: @harrymc Is it possible that the stick perfectly manages to connect but is struggling with a certain network?

Comment: Doesn't sound likely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no tech expert, but a couple of months ago I had a problem connecting to the internet with my laptop after a Windows update, when someone suggested resetting the IP configuration, which worked like a charm for me. Maybe see if this works for you.

1. Run command prompt (click Windows key then type "cmd").
2. Type in "ipconfig /release" (without quotes).
3. Let it run then type in "ipconfig/ renew".
4. Wait a few seconds and see if it connects.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a problem with this on a built-in card on a laptop as well. Have tried many things, but this seemed to work.
Go to device manager (right click the start button and Device manager is there), then go under Network adapters, then find your adapter (make sure it is plugged in through this entire thing) Disable it then reboot. After reboot go back and reenable it. That is what has worked before when I had a problem like this on windows 10

Hope this helps.